# live usb wont work with windows 8

Tags: usb, live-usb

Everytime I try starting the computer with the flash drive in, It just flashes the Lenovo logo as it would normally do, but except it does not stop. it looks as if it is in an infinet loop. As soon i take the flash drive out it just starts windows 8 normally.

I tried using 3 different usb ports, both the 64 and 32 bit versions, and 2 different softwares for putting it on to the actual flash drive. Same thing everytime. But when i go try it on an old XP computer i have, its just fine.

I think it has something to with the BIOS on windows 8 (if it is even still called that), its definetly different from anything else i have seen in older systems, and harder to use.

This is beyond annoying and Ive just ran out of ideas. I just want it to work.

I have a lenovo P500 with Windows 8

Comment: which distro/version are trying ?

Comment: Did you change the boot order in bios?

Comment: About the version, Yea i should of said that. 12.04 ubuntu, i beileve. I could also not find out how to change the boot order in the bios, but windows 8 has a button for restarting and then booting from the usb.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the USB drive with Universal USB installer under Windows http://www.pendrivelinux.com/downloads/Universal-USB-Installer/Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.5.2.exe

it works great with me -every time.

I would suggest redownloading the ISO file

Comment: Ive done that. the Ubuntu and the Installer are fine and tested with another computer.

Comment: depending on your PC and BIOS model, try to change mode to BIOS instead of UEFI and recheck

Comment: Where would that be done?

Comment: i'm afraid you should look around your BIOS setting. it might be there or not depending on your model.

Comment: also disable Secure boot - if enabled

Comment: would trying to boot in legacy be something to try?

Comment: you mean legacy USB, sure give it a try